# What is the benefit of maintaining tags in System V init files?

Tags: rhel5, init.d

This page describes tags that can be put into System V init scripts.

http://mcs.une.edu.au/doc/initscripts/sysvinitfiles

In RHEL5, chkconfig will parse the chkconfig tag.

```
# chkconfig: 2345 20 80
```

In RHEL5, what other tools parse and utilize the other tags?  What benefit is attained by having `processname`, `pidfile` or `config` tags in my scripts?

Comment: for tags information man chkconfig